# the javascript object is updated, but not the html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax request to retrieve some data from the database, and on success, I update an html table with the data retreived.
the problem is that when I select an element using `document.getElementByClassName(className)[0].innerHTML = newValue`
I see in the console that the `newValue` appears in the table I selected, but in the UI, nothing changed.

my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('tablesorter').length; i++){
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName('tablesorter')[i];
    exp_id = table.getAttribute("data-exp_id");
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'get_something.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : { 
            expression : exp_id
        }, 
        success : function(data) {
            something= "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                value = data[i];
                something+= '<tr><td>' + value.a + '</td><td>' + value.b + '</td><td>' + value.c + '</td><td>' + value.d+ '</td></tr>';

            }

            table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML = something;
            console.log(ailleurs);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why are you using jQuery for ajax and not for DOM stuff?

Comment: also, please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can try it ourselves

Comment: a jQueryish solution will be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5Qt8S/1/

Comment: The problem is with your loop. All your callback functions are updating the last table, not the `i`th.

Comment: @Markasoftware I tried jquery for DOM, and I had the same issue

Comment: What @Barmar said, there's no special scope in a for loop, variables are overwritten and ajax is async.

Comment: @adeneo you have accedentally answered the question, the solution was to set the ajax as async: false

Comment: add it as an answer, give an explanation to this issue if possible, and I will accept the answer

Comment: Nope, that was not the correct answer, you just made **asynchronous** javascript synchronous.

Comment: @kdureidy - please don't set this to `async: false`.  That will just lock up the browser during the ajax call.  Learn how to program your loops correctly inside the ajax handlers by creating a closure.   The referenced duplicate shows how to do it.  Or, if you use jQuery for the iteration, it already creates an independent scope that will also help you solve the issue.

Comment: What @jfriend00 said would look something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/7vefm/1/

Comment: I tried the jQuery    "each"    but I had the same issue, nothing changed to the UI, while in the log, I see the tables objects are updated with the values I've got from the AJAX request

Comment: OK, Now i understand what you mean, and you are right, problem solved. I created a function that will do the AJAX request, and then called this function within a loop without setting asynq: false.
please add it as answer so I can I accept it.